# inserte data with incremented values

Tags: sql, sybase

I have this table tab1

```
name
-----
'big'
'smal'
'bird'
```

tab2

```
id name
-- ---
1  empty
2  empty
3  empty
4  empty
```

I want to insert the name from tab1 to tab2 with incremented id 
this is desired result

```
  id name
    -- ---
    1  empty
    2  empty
    3  empty
    4  empty
    5  'big'
    6  'smal'
    7  'bird'
```

Comment: Table tab2 definition.

Comment: @jarlh sorry i didnt understand

Comment: is my answer not clear @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is for `table2` to define `id` as an *identity* column.  You do this when you define the table:

```
create table table2 (
    id int identity primary key,
    . . .
```

Then you can simply do:

```
insert into table2(name)
     select name
     from table1;
```

You should consider defining the table correctly, if it is not.  But, you can also do this in more recent versions of Sybase doing:

```
insert into table2(name)
     select maxid + row_number() over (order by name), name
     from table1 cross join
          (select max(id) as maxid from table2) x;
```

Note:  This will assign the id values in alphabetical order.

Comment: which sybase version it include this function ?

Comment: @Moudiz . . . Google:  "sybase row_number()"